# Relationship between model and controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am a beginner, i got doubt regarding model and controller name specification i have created model name as "login" weather the controller name should plural of model name like "logins" ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on [naming conventions](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7).

The `Model` is usually singular and the `Controller` is usually plural.

Comment: def index
    @mails = Mail.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @mails }
    end
  end

  # GET /mails/1
  # GET /mails/1.xml
  def show
    @mail = Mail.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @mail }
    end
  end         what is the difference between  def index
    @mails = Mail and def show
    @mail = Mail where index contains @mails and show contains @mail what it defines for ?